# Can we search a filename in the whole computer using java

Tags: java, server, file-search

i am making a client server program in which client request a filename to server and server search that file and then send that file to client if found. In my case server is my computer. So, is there any method using which i can search that file in  my whole computer in less time.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15624226/java-search-for-files-in-a-directory

Comment: But i dont want to enter the directory name

Comment: So set your root directory as a default.

Comment: Can you show us what did you try ?

Comment: You could use a FileVisitor http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/FileVisitor.html

Answer (score 0):

this is example for TCP Server in java:

```
public class TCPServer {

public static void main(String argv[]) {
    String clientSentence;
    //String capitalizedSentence;
    ServerSocket welcomeSocket = null;
    int port = 0;

    try {
        //port = Integer.valueOf(argv[0]);
        port = 6868;
    } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException aio) {
        System.out.println("Insert port");
        System.exit(1);
    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
        System.out.println("Argument must be a number");
        System.exit(1);
    }
    try {
        welcomeSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
        System.out.println("started TCP listening on " + String.valueOf(port));
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        System.out.println("Could not listen on TCP port = " + String.valueOf(port));
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        if (welcomeSocket != null) {
            while (true) {
                Socket connectionSocket = welcomeSocket.accept();
                System.out.println("connected-----------------------");
                BufferedReader inFromClient = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connectionSocket.getInputStream()));
                DataOutputStream outToClient = new DataOutputStream(connectionSocket.getOutputStream());
                while ((clientSentence = inFromClient.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println("File name: " + clientSentence);
                    if (clientSentence.equals("filename")) {
                        outToClient.writeBytes("this file exists\n");
                    }
                }
                inFromClient.close();
                connectionSocket.close();
                System.out.println("Disconnected-------------------");
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            welcomeSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
}
```

this is client for sending filename and listening server reply.For example file path which you found by file name:

```
public class TCPRequester {
public static String sendRequestToServer(String serverIp, int serverPort, String command) throws Exception {

    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    // Create input and output streams to read from and write to the server

    Socket socket = new Socket(serverIp, serverPort);// Connect to the server
    PrintStream out = new PrintStream(socket.getOutputStream()); // Create output streams to write to the server
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));//Create input streams to read from the server
    out.write(command.getBytes());

    // Read data from the server until we finish reading the document
    String line;
    while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
        result.append(line);
        System.out.println( line );
    }
    System.out.println("finished response");

    // Close our streams
    in.close();
    out.close();
    socket.close();

    return result.toString();
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        System.out.println(sendRequestToServer("localhost", 6868, "filename\n"));
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(TCPRequester.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
}
```