# How to get the file path of a file

Tags: java, filepath

If I already have an existing file and I want to know its path using only its name, how can I do this?

I have the following code, but it return the name of the file even when it does not exists:

```
PathMatcher matcher = FileSystems.getDefault().getPathMatcher("glob:**.{java,class}");

Path filename = Paths.get("Go,mvDep.java");
if (matcher.matches(filename)) {
    System.out.println(filename);
}
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: What do you mean _even when it does not exists_? Exist where? Do you mean on the file system? What part of your code do you think should check for the existence of the file? Why do you think so?

Comment: Yes, I mean in the file system. I see what you are saying. But is there a method that given a file name, it will return the path of it by searching it in the whole system?

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15624430/3794552

Answer (score 0):

I think the core of your confusion is that a `Path` does not necessarily represent a file on your computer.  It is simply a Java object that represents a conceptual object in a file system.  In the same way that you could construct a `new Person("John", "Smith")` without actually knowing anyone named 'John Smith', you can construct a `Path` regardless of whether or not a file exists at the given location.

Once you have a `Path` there are a number of things you can do with it, including check if it exists via [`Files.exists()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#exists-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.LinkOption...-), or create it with [`Files.createFile()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#createFile-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.attribute.FileAttribute...-).  Generally speaking, the `Files` class lets you inspect and work with the actual file system objects a `Path` represents.

The intent of a `PathMatcher` is similarly disconnected from the actual file system; it exists to  to determine if a given `Path` fits the `PathMatcher`'s pattern - it's basically a `Path`-specific regular expression engine.

So what your code is actually doing is:

1. Creating a [glob](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)) that will match any path which ends in `.java` or `.class` (regardless of whether such a path exists anywhere).
2. Constructing a relative `Path` to a file called `Go,mvDep.java`.  Implicitly this path is relative to the current [working directory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory), but you could pass it to [`Path.resolve()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html#resolve-java.nio.file.Path-) to create a new `Path` referring to a file in a different location.
3. Checking if the path `Go,mvDep.java` matches your glob, which it does since it ends in `.java`, so it prints the path.

It sounds like what you actually want is to *find* an *existing* file with the name `Go,mvDep.java`.  If so, you want to use [`Files.find()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#find-java.nio.file.Path-int-java.util.function.BiPredicate-java.nio.file.FileVisitOption...-) to search a directory and return a stream of the files that match a `BiPredicate<Path, BasicFileAttributes> matcher` you define.  Your `matcher` might look something like this:

```
new BiPredicate<Path, BasicFileAttributes>() {
  public boolean test(Path path, BasicFileAttributes attributes) {
    return matcher.matches(path);
  }
}
```

Or in Lambda syntax simply:

```
(p, a) -> matcher.matches(p)
```