# Java open files with given extension in a directory hierarchy

Tags: java, file, java-io

I implemented a recursive method to traverse a directory hierarchy looking for files with a given extension; however I'm not convinced this is the easiest way and it involves `isDirectory()`, `listFiles()`, etc.

Is there a way to do that without explicitly writing a recursive method: I'm thinking something like `find` that would directly return a list of files or filenames (with their full path) at any level in the structure matching the correct extension. I would then just loop over these files.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15624226/java-search-for-files-in-a-directory

Comment: Look into Files.walk()

Answer (score 4):

You can also use [Apache Commons FileUtis](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html)

```
FileUtils.listFiles(dir, extensions, true);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `java.io.File#listFiles()`;

```
public File[] finder( String dirName){
    File dir = new File(dirName);
    return dir.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {
        public boolean accept(File dir, String filename){
            return filename.endsWith(".txt"); 
        }
    });
}
```

***Edit:***
If you would like to discover the directory in recursive take a look at

> [FileUtilslistFiles(File directory, String[] extensions, boolean recursive)](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#listFiles(java.io.File,%20java.lang.String[],%20boolean))

with a filter.

Comment: This is not recursive, i. e. it does not search in sub-folders

Comment: Thanks, indeed I found an answer involving `FilenameFilter` in the question linked in the comment. But your solution is even shorter.

Comment: @AhmadWabbi the author asked explicitly for a *non* recursive and this is truly the most simple and fast (as this overload does not create a `File` object for every found file) way to achieve his goal

Comment: Maybe I was not clear: I want it to recursively explore a directory tree, but without implementing myself a recursive method call.

Comment: Well, I understood that he still wants to search sub-folders (implicit recursion) simply by calling a method, i.e. without explicit recursion

Comment: `FileUtils.listFiles` is better in both cases: recursive or not.

Comment: Basically it does the same inside, but yes it takes less effort to use it.

Comment: Thanks that's exactly what I needed.