# How do I search for files with some extension and remove the extension while retaining the file name and leaving rest of the files unchanged?

Tags: java

I have these files in the folder:
`E:/New Folder/image.png`
`E:/New Folder/file.pdf.jpg`
`E:/New Folder/newtext.txt.jpg`
`E:/New Folder/download.pdf`

**I want to remove `.jpg` extension from multiple files in the same folder while retaining its original name. How can i do this in Java??**

New contents of the folders must be these:
`E:/New Folder/image.png`
`E:/New Folder/file.pdf`
`E:/New Folder/newtext.txt`
`E:/New Folder/download.pdf`
**Thanks!!**

**I figured this out..**

```
import java.io.File;;
class removeExtension {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    File[] fileList = directory.listFiles();
    String dirPath = "C:/Temp";
    int i;
      for(File file : fileList){
        if(file.getName().endsWith(".jpg")) {
                File dir = new File(dirPath);
                String[] oldfiles = dir.list();
                String[] newfiles = new String[oldfiles.length];
                    for(i = 0; i <= oldfiles.length - 1; i++) {
                        newfiles[i] = oldfiles[i].replace(".jpg", "");
                        }
                    for (i = 0; i <=oldfiles.length - 1; i++) {
                        File oldfile = new File("C:/Temp" + oldfiles[i]);
                        File newfile = new File("C:/Temp" + newfiles[i]);
                        oldfile.renameTo(newfile);
                        }

            }

        }
}
}
```

Comment: What about `replace(".jpg","")`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java - Search for files in a directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15624226/java-search-for-files-in-a-directory)

Comment: @KarlNicholas I want something beyond searching.. Please help me out.. Thanks!

Comment: Not here to write code for you.

Comment: @mhatch Thank you!