# Intermediate operation in Java streams

Tags: java, collections, java-8, java-stream

In java 8, I am using Streams to print the output, but size is coming as 0. Why?

```
public class IntermediateryAndFinal {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Stream<String> stream = Stream.of("one", "two", "three", "four", "five");

        Predicate<String> p1 = Predicate.isEqual("two");
        Predicate<String> p2 = Predicate.isEqual("three");

        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

        stream.peek(System.out::println)
            .filter(p1.or(p2))
            .peek(list::add);
        System.out.println("Size = "+list.size());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ideally you should not mutate an external list, instead you can use `Collectors.toList()` to collect it in a list:

```
List<String> list = stream.peek(System.out::println)
            .filter(p1.or(p2))
            .collect(Collectors.toList()); // triggers the evaluation of the stream
System.out.println("Size = "+list.size());
```

In your example, *streams are evaluated only when a terminal operation* like

```
allMatch()
anyMatch() 
noneMatch() 
collect() 
count() 
forEach() 
min() 
max() 
reduce()
```

are encountered.

Answer (score 2):

Since you haven't yet completed the stream operation i.e. `peek` is an intermediate operation. You must use a ***terminal operation*** for that to be executed still.

*Suggestion*: Instead perform such operation using terminal operation such as `collect`

```
List<String> list = stream.peek(System.out::println)
        .filter(p1.or(p2))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Additionally: Adding a `peek` post `filter` to observe the values could be a little tricky in observation, as for the following code

```
List<String> list = stream.peek(System.out::println)
        .filter(p1.or(p2))
        .peek(System.out::println) // addition
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

the output would look like :

> ```
> one
> two
> two // filtered in
> three
> three // filtered in
> four
> five
> ```

Answer (score 1):

The streams are lazy. You mast call a terminal operation like `forEach`:

```
stream.peek(System.out::println)
      .filter(p1.or(p2))
      .forEach(list::add);
```

In case you want to use `peek` as intermediary operation for debugging purposes then you must call a terminal operation afterwards:

```
stream.peek(System.out::println)
      .filter(p1.or(p2))
      .peek(list::add);
      .<any terminal operation here>();
```

Btw, if you want just store all the filtered values in a list, then better use `collect(toList())`.

Comment: operations such as modifications of data structures should be avoided in terminal operations (`forEach`) and in the latter approach, there is chance of peek not being executed, for e.g. Java-9 and above implementation of `count()`.

Comment: For further details refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48221783/stream-peek-method-in-java-8-vs-java-9

Comment: @nullpointer Yes, indeed. I was answering the OP's question *"Why?"*. So the answer is in the very first line. But of course I always recommend avoiding mutation of state while processing streams.

Answer (score 0):

All you've done with `filter` and `peek` is set up a chain of actions to apply to the stream. You haven't actually caused any of them to run yet. You have to add a terminal operation such as `count`. (Another answer suggested using `forEach` to add to the list, but I think you're specifically trying to use the intermediate operation `peek`.)

Comment: there is a chance of `peek` not being executed, for e.g. Java-9 and above implementation of `count()`. Further details - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48221783/stream-peek-method-in-java-8-vs-java-9

Comment: Thanks. Learn something new every day!