# Java stream check results of multiple calls using map

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, command-pattern

I have the following problem regarding the correct use of streams and map.

The problem is the following

I have a method that reads a file from input and inserts record in a database, in a few words it performs some **side effects**

Furthermore, the same function returns some sort of a state, let's say a boolean (I have some degree of freedom about this) that states that the function went well.

```
public static boolean execute(String filename){

    // Perform some side effects (e.g. write on DB)

    return true; // or false according to some criteria;

}
```

Then, I have to call it with let's say two files and I have to detect if at least one went well (i.e. if at least one execution returned true)

My simple solution is: (a sort of simplified version of the command pattern)

```
public class Entrypoint {

    public static boolean myFunction(String input) {
        System.out.println("executed..." + input);
        return !input.equals("B");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<String> lst = Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F");

        long callsOk = lst.stream().map(Entrypoint::myFunction)
            // .filter(x -> x.equals(true)).count();
            .filter(x -> x).count(); // Better, as suggested by Donat

        System.out.println("OK=" + callsOk);

    }
}
```

This work, fine, the output is:

```
executed...A
executed...B
executed...C
executed...D
executed...E
executed...F
OK=5
```

That is right because it should fail (return false) for "B"

**The question is:**

Is it fine to use a function like myFunction:

- **whose prime purpose is to perform side effects**

and

- the purpose of its return value is just to give the status of the operation performed (success or not) and no other kind of data

inside a map in order to count the number of yields == true?

Or am I messing up, and there is a better solution to handle this?

Comment: For the awareness - [Java8 Vs Java9 behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48221783/stream-peek-method-in-java-8-vs-java-9).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two answers.

First: Yes, it works. You can do it like this.

Second: Do not do this! Streams are for functional programming and functional programming is about avoiding side effects. This is kind of a misuse and it can be confusing. Think about more complicated cases! Someone familiar with functional programming will probably not expect this misuse.

This means: You should not use streams if you have imperative code with side effects or stateful operations. In this case a classical for each loop is the better choice. This is a matter of style. In many cases (like this one) the solution with streams is working well, but it is bad style.

Another issue: When you avoid side effects in streams, you can easily change them to parallel execution.

By the way, `filter(x -> x.equals(true))` can be simplified to `filter(x -> x)`.

Comment: Is there a "right"/"suggested" way to achieve my goal? (i.e. execute the functions and count the number of results == true)

Comment: I would suggest to do it in a for each loop.

Comment: @Donat: How executing code in a for loop, rather than using streams, make a difference here?  I somehow miss the point here. can you please elaborate ?

Comment: @Sahil Gupta: Both solutions (stream and for each) are working correctly in this case. It is a matter of style which one to use. Please ask a more specific question, if you still do not understand. I will try to answer.