# List all media files on startup in JavaFx

Tags: java, javafx, media-player, scenebuilder

I have created a media player using the media class of JavaFX. What I want is that the media player should search all media files available in the system on startup. is there any way to do this, any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: There are a **lot** of ways to do this. What have you tried so far? Do you have a specific problem in your attempts?

Comment: You can use ideas from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15624226/java-search-for-files-in-a-directory). I would search for file extensions and add them to a `List`.

Comment: Of course you could search every directory on the hard drive but don't be surprised if this takes multiple minutes, if not hours...

Comment: you could ask the user to specify which directories contains his/her media files some media players do so

Comment: @Zephyr I am new in JavaFX and I have tried nothing till now it does manually means user add files to the playlist, I want it to be done by the player itself